# Assigning function to dynamically added HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery and JavaScript I am trying to write some code that setups up one or more widgets. The widget accepts text in an `input` and adds it to a `ul` when a `button` is clicked.

Then items are added to the `ul`, a click listener is a setup to remove a specific item when clicked.

**The code looks like this:**

```js
    function WidgetThing(className) {
     
      var items = [];
      
      function removeItem(e) {
        var idx = parseInt($(e.target).attr('data-index'));
        items.splice(idx, 1);
        updateItems();
      }
    
     function updateItems() {
       var ul = $('.' + className + ' .items ul');
        ul.html('');
       items.forEach(function(item, idx) {
         ul.append('<li data-index="' + idx + '">' + item + '</li>');
        });
        ul.on('click', 'li', removeItem);
      }
    
      $('.' + className + ' .add-button').click(function(e) {
       var input = $('.' + className + ' input');
       items.push(input.val());
        input.val('');
        updateItems();
      });
    
    }
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
     WidgetThing('widget1');
      WidgetThing('widget2');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Widget1
    <div class="widget1">
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" />
        <button class='add-button'>Add Item</button>
      </div>
    
      <div class="items">
        <ul></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    Widget2
    <div class="widget2">
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" />
        <button class='add-button'>Add Item</button>
      </div>
    
      <div class="items">
        <ul></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This works fine for adding items.

However, if I click the item to remove it, it also removes *all* items below the one selected.

How can I get this code to work? Am I taking the wrong approach?

**Update Note:** In the real app my `updateItems()` function has some side effects, so I need to take this approach to removing items from the array.

Comment: You need `removeItem` pass the `idx` to `updateItems` so it will know which one to remove.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, I don't think this is the issue. The logic is that the `removeItem` function uses the `data` attribute to remove the clicked item from the array, then it re-renderes the list.

Comment: I think you are going about this the wrong way. You are effectively maintaining two lists (the array and the `ul`) that you now have to keep in sync. Lose the array and just manage the `li` items in the list. Removing one is as simple as `this.parent.removeChild(this)` and adding one is just `list.appendChild`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus it's possible I am approaching this the wrong way. Basically I need to dump the list as a JSON string in a hidden `input` field... So whenever the `updateItems()` is called it will updated both the `<li>` and the hidden JSON field.

Comment: Not a problem. Just update the `li` elements and then you can create a temporary array to stringify into JSON like this `let json = JSON.stringify(Array.from($("li")))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/94ncdzpj/3/)**.

That could be achieved with less code than this, you could attach two events one to the buttons and another to the `li` elements for the remove :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.add-button').click(function() {
    var items = $(this).closest('.controls').next('.items');
    $('ul', items).append('<li>' + $(this).prev('input').val() + '</li>');
  });

  $('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

Here is a working snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.add-button').click(function() {
    var items = $(this).closest('.controls').next('.items');
    $('ul', items).append('<li>' + $(this).prev('input').val() + '</li>');
  });

  $('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Widget1
<div class="widget1">
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" />
    <button class='add-button'>Add Item</button>
  </div>

  <div class="items">
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
</div>

Widget2
<div class="widget2">
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" />
    <button class='add-button'>Add Item</button>
  </div>

  <div class="items">
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Appreciate the response. In my real app I am doing many more things in my Widget code... The example I shared is just a highly simplified example to demonstrate my issue... Basically, I need to maintain the `items` array and `updateItems` function.

Comment: Yes, I see, anyway the use of `$(this)` and the other functions to get the relative items will simplify the things for you... we may need more details to see what kind of things that force you to use this approach.